# Link inside the node to expand it

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a collapsible tree having a link to expand the current node (in stead of clicking the node using on.("click",clicked) method). Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilambar9/A72tC/)

```
nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
.attr("width", rectW)
.attr("height", rectH)
.append("xhtml:body")
.style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
.html(function (d) { return "<a href='#' onclick=\x22clicked(" + source + ")\x22>"+d.name+"</a>"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your `source` variable is converted to string, so you don't actually pass object to `clicked` function;

You can rewrite this to append link like this:

```
nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
.attr("width", rectW)
.attr("height", rectH)
.append("xhtml:body")
.style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'") 
.append("a").html(function(d){return d.name;})
.attr('href', '#')
.on('click', function(){
    clicked(source);
    });
```

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a36hD/2/)

To make it work for clicked node (instead of always parent node) you can replace `source` by clicked function argument

```
.on('click', function(d){
    clicked(d);
    });
```

another updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a36hD/3/)

Comment: you're welcome! please accept it as a correct answer if it solved your problem